# How to use Kotlinx serialization with jvm plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, kotlinx.serialization

I can't use Kotlinx serialization with the Kotlin JVM plugin

In [the instructions for Groovy DSL](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#using-the-plugins-block):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.5.0'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.5.0'
}
```

Because I already use the `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`, I want to use it with the JVM plugin but the instructions do not explicitly show how.

In `build.gradle`, I tried using:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.0'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.5.0'
    ...
}
```

In code:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
```

And, I get a compilation error (`Unresolved reference: serialization`). How can I use kotlinx serialization with the JVM plugin? Also, I need it in the Groovy DSL syntax. [The instructions](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#using-the-plugins-block) already show it for the Kotlin DSL but I don't use it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin is not sufficient to use Kotlinx Serialization, you also need the runtime library to use classes from the `kotlinx.serialization.*` packages.
This is covered in the docs:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#dependency-on-the-json-library

In Gradle, this means you need to add Kotlinx serialization as a dependency in the `dependencies` block:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.1"
}
```

If you need other formats than JSON, you'll need to add the corresponding artifact instead.